# Plot Slope Fields Given Differential Equation

Tags: code-golf, ascii-art, calculus

Slope fields or direction fields, are a graphical representation of the solutions to a first-order differential equation of a scalar function. A slope field shows the slope of a differential equation at certain vertical and horizontal intervals on the cartesian plane, and can be used to determine the approximate tangent slope at a point on a curve, where the curve is some solution to the differential equation. For example consider the differential equation:

$$
\frac{dy}{dx} = \frac{y-4x}{x-y}
$$

The corresponding slope field will look like:

[image]

Another example with this differential equation:

$$
\frac{dy}{dx} = \frac{x-y}{x-2y}
$$

[image]

Your task is to generate such slope fields in the console with characters of text. You are to print the following for each coordinate pair:

- `/` If the differential equation evaluated at the point \$(x, y)\$ is positive.
- `\` If the differential equation evaluated at the point \$(x, y)\$ is negative.
- `-` If the differential equation evaluated at the point \$(x, y) = 0\$.
- `|` If the differential equation evaluated at the point \$(x, y)\$ is undefined.

The inputs are a string and a number consisting of:

- Expression string that can be evaluated (or parsed if you have to).
- A number that outlines the radius of the plot from \$(0, 0)\$.

The expression string can use any built-in mathematical function and will only either \$x\$ or \$y\$ as variables. Any combination of logarithms, (inverse and/or hyperbolic) trigonometric functions, or functions like `sqrt(), pow(), exp(), abs()` may be used in the expression. The plot radius may also be 0, which means only print one character containing the slope at the origin. A sample input may look something like:

```py
plotRadius = 10
expression = "(x - y) / (x - 2 * y)"
```

Notice how both the boundaries of the plot follow: \$ -\text{plotRadius} \leq x, y \leq \text{plotRadius}\$. This results in the following slope field being displayed:

```
/ / / / / / / / / / / / / / / / / / / / — 
/ / / / / / / / / / / / / / / / / / / — \ 
/ / / / / / / / / / / / / / / / / / — \ \ 
/ / / / / / / / / / / / / / / / / — \ \ \ 
/ / / / / / / / / / / / / / / / — \ \ \ \ 
/ / / / / / / / / / / / / / / — \ \ \ \ | 
/ / / / / / / / / / / / / / — \ \ \ | / / 
/ / / / / / / / / / / / / — \ \ | / / / / 
/ / / / / / / / / / / / — \ | / / / / / / 
/ / / / / / / / / / / — | / / / / / / / / 
/ / / / / / / / / / | / / / / / / / / / / 
/ / / / / / / / | — / / / / / / / / / / / 
/ / / / / / | \ — / / / / / / / / / / / / 
/ / / / | \ \ — / / / / / / / / / / / / / 
/ / | \ \ \ — / / / / / / / / / / / / / / 
| \ \ \ \ — / / / / / / / / / / / / / / / 
\ \ \ \ — / / / / / / / / / / / / / / / / 
\ \ \ — / / / / / / / / / / / / / / / / / 
\ \ — / / / / / / / / / / / / / / / / / / 
\ — / / / / / / / / / / / / / / / / / / / 
— / / / / / / / / / / / / / / / / / / / /
```

Please separate each point with a space.

Comment: Is a function that takes x and y acceptable as input?

Comment: Are you talking about \$\frac{dy}{dx} = x \wedge y\$?

Comment: No, I mean a function `f(x, y)` which is passed to our program.

Comment: Yes, but keep in mind, the "function" is actually the derivative.

Comment: Does this have to be approximated ASCII art, or would submissions in e.g. Desmos be allowed? Would drawing an actual graph be a separate question?

Comment: you should add a test case to check that `x` and `y` are in the correct direction (for example `x+y`)

Answer (score 1):

## [Julia 1.0](http://julialang.org/), 90 bytes

```julia
N\~=-(r=-N:N).|>y->println(join(r.|>x->abs(x~y)<Inf ? "\\-/"[Int(sign(x~y))+2] : "|"," "))
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##JYm9DoIwEIB3n@Jy01U5EUZC68zSF7AOGIIpIdUUTNqE8Oq10e37mT6z7auQkja7ZPKSdaPFeVOR1dtbt86Oppd15HMLrPrHQmGPou3cCFdAY7jEW@dWWuzT/ZY41XdoADcsEFCINIwUiihAAgVgyFT@qYZjtkN1McOYvg)

takes `plotRadius\df`, where `df` is a black-box function and prints the plot

Comment: We need to update Julia on TIO!

Comment: @graffe TIO is not supported anymore, there's no new languages. There is https://ato.pxeger.com/run with the latest version of Julia

Answer (score 1):

## [Burlesque](https://github.com/FMNSSun/Burlesque), <s>71</s> 62 bytes

```
pes1Jngjr@sajJ<>cpm{%1!{{@0.<}'\{@0.>}'/{@0==}'-{1}'|}cn}jcosp
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##SyotykktLixN/f@/ILXY0CsvPavIoTgxy8vGLrkgt1rVULG62sFAz6ZWPQZE29Wq6wNpW9tadd1qw1r1mtrkvNqs5Pzigv//DQ24quMKuEpSlCqUissUgHQlkOYC8tLLFIBsIKmni8I10tMCiujp1wIA)

First stab, still some optimisation to be done

```
pes1       # Parse function and save 
J          # Dup
ng         # Negate
jr@        # Range -n..n
sa         # Get length for chunking later
jJ<>cp     # Transform to -n..n x -n..n
m{         # Map
 %1!       # Call function
 {
  {@0.<}'\ # If <0  \
  {@0.>}'/ # If >0  /
  {@0==}'- # If ==0 -
  {1}'|    # else   |
 }cn       # Condition
}
jco        # Chunks of len
sp         # Pretty output
```

Comment: I think you should reverse the `y` axis (check with `x+y`)

Answer (score 0):

## Python 2, 122 bytes

```py
def g(r,e):
 q=range(-r,r+1)
 for x in q:
    l=""
    for y in q:
     try:l+="-/\\"[cmp(e(-x,y),0)]+" "
     except:l+="| "
    print l
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##NYxBDoIwFETXcopJV62UCCwxnEQNQWm1CbTlWw1NvDtWEnczk/fGx/Bwtl41uQldp1/hRarrYCbvKGAwb/M0zq6D0tCcpBJNhrml3t4VL0hSXokM2hEWGIu5yXZjy1i2@03xPyFQbMa8ZcXhfGan2@R5shcZhSzFJWdgxwSp5aZ82LgP0oUnYwPGVfOqlGM/XYceyWn4ggJR4IAt1dinJtYv)

Takes an integer and a function as input, prints the result.